# inport csv file into hive table got null column name

Tags: hive

I am new to hadoop hive. I am using open source hadoop 2.7.1 hive 1.2.2. It is installed on ubuntu a single node cluster. I have 106 rows and 30 columns data in csv file. I import it into hive table using following code:

`CREATE TABLE clinicaldatabc (comp_tcga_id String, gender String, age_inti_diag int, ER_status String, PR_status String, HER2_final_status String, Tumor String, Tumor_T1_code String, Node String, Node_coded String, Metastasis String, Metastasis_coded String, AJCC_Stage String, Converted_stage String, Survival_dt_from String, Vital_Status String, d_to_date_of_last_contact int, d_to_Day_of_Death int, OS_event int,OS_time int, PAM50_mRNA String, SigClust_unsupervised_mRNA int, SigClust_intrinsic_mRNA int, miRNA_clusters int, methylation_clusters int,RPPA_clusters int, CN_clusters int, integrated_clusters_with_PAM50 int, integrated_cluster_no_exp int, integrated_clusters_unsup_exp int) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';`

Then I got null column name: 
[first half of returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JYmH.png)
[second half of returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTrxO.png)

Please help me how to solve it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NULL column names in Hive query result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40573474/null-column-names-in-hive-query-result)

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [NULL column names in Hive query result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40573474/null-column-names-in-hive-query-result)

The first thing to note here is that the NULL values occur in columns that are not of type string

Answer (score 0):

Have a refer

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ejREGandTEST(
DBN STRING,
School_name STRING,
Year_of_SHST INT,
Grade_level INT,
Enrollment INT,
Number_of_registered INT,
Number_students_SHSAT INT)
row format delimited fields terminated by ','
location "/user/ebin/kaggleData/csv"
TBLPROPERTIES("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```