# How to load a file to HIVE with columns name mentioned in the file?

Tags: hive

I have text file that I have loaded to my newly created hive table. When I got the file, it had the column names as well. So,I deleted the column names from the file and loaded only the data. However, I am getting "null" for the first two rows, and then the data is starting.The table has 39 columns.I am pretty sure that the null values are for the column names.

Below is the output of the select query

```
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULLNULL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
600002158100    2000-02-15      2018-09-24 07:06:26     63      1       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0   00       0       0       0       0               "S"     0       NULL    "Y"     "N"     "N"     0       7       "xyz"  "MEDIUM"        "abc" "pqr"  "Sam"   1       "chris"        1999-07-31

1)So, do I had to load the files including the column names with it? 
2) I still believe that the file that needs to be loaded need not have column names in it, just the data. please correct me if I am wrong.
```

Please let me know my mistake.

New output after using tblproperties

```
abc      xyz        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    pqr       name  NULL     NULL    age    NULL    NULL    city    country       date     year     month
```

I.e. when I fire "select * from tbl limi4", I get the header names and then the data. Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the tablproperties while creating the able ( or alter later) to skip the header.

```
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1")
```

Here **count** shows how many first rows represents the header.

Comment: So, in my case , I will be using "1", as the header is in first row, right?

Comment: @learner if only first row represents header, then yes 1. However, if you set this you no longer need to remove header from your file.

Comment: When I used that tblproperties. I am getting output which I have updated in my original post

Comment: it seems like datatype mismatch, could you change the datatype to string and run again.

Comment: No, I cannot change the data types, as there are data those are float, integer as well. However, as a work around, I removed the header from my file, and used the tblproperties as well, that seems to be working . Below link may also give more insight on the whole situation.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40573474/null-column-names-in-hive-query-result

Comment: however, if you have any more solutions that I could try, please mention

Comment: @learner if you will remove the header from file and will keep the `tablproperties`, doesn't that discard the first row, I am not pretty sure here.

Comment: @learner if you source is file, it's always a good idea to create your first table (raw or landing) with all column as **string** datatype and create another table (staging)  and apply datatype on that and do other cleansing, this way you will avoid problems and would be easy to identify errors those are giving issues,